# Extract lines between two line numbers in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

How is this possible in shell using **sed** or any other filter

Lets say that i have two specific line numbers in two variables `$line1` and `$line2` and i want to extract lines between these two lines like this

```
cat my_file_path | command $line1 $line2
```

Example if my file is:

1:bbb

2:cccc

3:dddd

4:eeeee

My output should be if i do:

```
cat my_file_path | command 1 3
```

Output

```
bbb
cccc
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

without testing:

```
awk -v s="$line1" -v e="$line2" 'NR>s&&NR<e' file
```

you can control the "inclusive/exclusive" with `>= or <=`

if you want to make it safe for leading/trailing spaces in your shell var:

```
 awk -v s="$line1" -v e="$line2" 'NR>1*s&&NR<1*e' file
```

Answer (score 30):

Using sed:

```
$ cat my_file_path | sed -n "${line1},${line2}p"
```

or, even better (`cat` is somehow redundant):

```
$ sed -n "${line1},${line2}p" my_file_path
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, since the OP does not want the lines `$line1`, `$line2` to be printed.

Comment: `sed` address ranges are inclusive, not exclusive, so your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a pipe with tail and head

```
tail -n +$line1 | head -n $((line2-line1))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You need to define line1 and line2, ex: line1=499, but it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I like it! Very clean and doesn't rely on sed or awk

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use on Centos, this example print lines between 100 and 200 from *myFile.log*

```
 awk 'NR >= 100 && NR <= 200' myFile.log
```

Other example lines before 100

```
awk  'NR <= 100' fileName.log
```

Note that You can also use >,< comparators.

This answer use NR variable aka record number, like line number, for more complex scenarios You can take a look to AWK build in variables: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

hope It helps

Answer (score 4):

Use **sed** to print the lines between (exclusively!) 100 and 200:

```
sed '1,100d;200,$d' file
```

**Optimization:** quit when end of range is encountered.

```
sed -n '1,100b;200q;p' file
```

The optimization uses the `b` command:

> `b` – branch unconditionally (that is: always jump to a label,  skipping
> or repeating other commands, without restarting a new cycle)
>
> [...] If the label is omitted the branch commands restart the cycle.
>
> [GNU sed manual: branching and flow control](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html)

**Test if the optimization was effective.** We'll use the [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) command-line benchmarking tool.

```bash
seq 1 1000000 >file # A file with 1,000,000 lines
hyperfine --warmup 5 \
  --command-name 'unoptimized' 'sed '\''1,100d;200,$d'\'' file' \
  --command-name 'optimized' 'sed -n '\''1,100b;200q;p'\'' file'
```

Result:

```
  'optimized' ran
   80.76 ± 45.66 times faster than 'unoptimized'
```

It stands to reason that the closer the lines are to be beginning of the file, the more beneficial the optimization will be.

We should test the opposite case too: lines of interest being at the *end* of the file:

```
hyperfine --warmup 5 \
  --command-name 'unoptimized' 'sed '\''1,900900d;1000000,$d'\'' file' \
  --command-name 'optimized' 'sed -n '\''1,900900b;1000000q;p'\'' file'
```

Result:

```
  'unoptimized' ran
    1.03 ± 0.05 times faster than 'optimized'
```

You see the optimized form yields a benefit for this case as well, although very small and within the margin of error.

Comment: How to make the sed include both start and end lines ?

Comment: @Enissay See [the answer by @Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759746/1157557) to use sed to include both the start and end lines. For example, `sed -n '100,200p'` will print lines 100 to 200 inclusively.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

Print lines 100 to 200 exclusive:

```bash
awk 'NR==200{p=0};p;NR==100{p=1}' file
```

**Optimization:** exit after the last line of the desired range has been printed:

```bash
awk 'NR==200{exit};p;NR==100{p=1}' file
```

**Test whether the optimization is effective.** We'll use the [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) command-line benchmarking tool.

```bash
seq 1 1000000 >file # Create a file with 1,000,000 lines

hyperfine --warmup 5 \
  --command-name 'unoptimized' 'awk '\''NR==200{p=0};p;NR==100{p=1}'\'' file' \
  --command-name 'optimized' 'awk '\''NR==200{exit};p;NR==100{p=1}'\'' file'
```

Result:

```
  'optimized' ran
   80.87 ± 33.69 times faster than 'unoptimized'
```

The above benchmark tested the case of the lines of interest being near the beginning of the file. We should also benchmark the opposite situation, with the lines of interesting being near the end:

```
hyperfine --warmup 5 \
  --command-name 'unoptimized' 'awk '\''NR==900100{p=0};p;NR==900000{p=1}'\'' file' \
  --command-name 'optimized' 'awk '\''NR==900100{exit};p;NR==900000{p=1}'\'' file'
```

Result:

```
  'optimized' ran
    1.11 ± 0.03 times faster than 'unoptimized'
```

The optimization was still a benefit, but not nearly as impactful.

**Compare awk with sed.** We'll compare the optimized awk with the optimized version of [my sed-based answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556787).

This time I select lines situated in the middle of the 1,000,000 line file:

```
hyperfine --warmup 5 \
  --command-name 'awk version' 'awk '\''NR==500100{exit};p;NR==500000{p=1}'\'' file' \
  --command-name 'sed version' 'sed -n '\''1,500000b;500100q;p'\'' file'
```

Result:

```
  'sed version' ran
    4.08 ± 0.09 times faster than 'awk version'
```

The sed version is significantly faster. It's also shorter. I'd give the sed version the edge in readability as well, but that's subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact answer but may be useful for anyone who does some manual log file investigations and wants to extract huge range of lines without much effort and line calculation, especially when `tail -f` is involved. Try `less the-big-log-file.log`:

- Open the file, go to starting position (e.g. with `/2021-11-21 19:00` search).
- Mark the current position with command `mM`
- Then go to ending position, e.g. `/2021-11-23 23:00` search.
- Extract line between mark point and ending position to separate file with the command: `|Mtee log-excerpt.txt`.

You will find log-excerpt.txt in your current dir with all lines between two search result positions.